# which adjective should i use for family of someone

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

I want to write a happy new year letter for someone(not very close, business partner) what adjective should i use in regard to his family for example : Dear Family , respectful family , beloved family , ... or any other word

Comment: You could just address it as:  "The Smiths" or "Bob and family"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood the situation, but I am puzzled as to why you would be writing directly to the family of your business partner rather than addressing it to the partner (with a mention of their family). Certainly, I think that would be unusual in Britain and the US.

If you wanted to explicitly include the partner's family in your New Year letter, I would suggest the following formula:

> Dear [first name of business partner] and family

If you also know the name of the partner's spouse, then

> Dear [first name of business partner, first name of spouse] and family *(if they have children)*

or

> Dear [first name of business partner] and [first name of spouse] *(if there are no children)*

are also possibilities.

Comment: i don't even know his family and i didn't even met the family ,so you are saying it is better to say "happy holiday to you and your family" instead of "to you and your respectful family"

Comment: @user2320445 - Yes, that would be the usual formulation. On a separate point, "respectful family" implies that the family is *full of respect;* I assume you really meant *respected family*.

Answer (score -1):

I think **kindred** would do. It means: one's family and relations.